# customize the display of getFeatureInfo

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I use the leaflet and the getfeatureInfo function to display the data of a wms layer belonging to the geoserver, I want to customize the display of retrieved table:
  [image]
I use this plugin https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938.

Comment: As this plugin is seemingly just a gist, you could take it and modify it for your needs, couldn't you? If not, please describe what the problem is, e.g. what you tried so far, what didn't work etc.

Comment: I want the table to be vertical like in this image https://sspinnovations.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Resize-beer-and-popups.png. but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the GeoServer instance you can control the style and layout of the response to a `getFeatureInfo` request using [templates](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/).

If you only have access to the endpoint then try requesting the response in `application/json` format and then use JavaScript to display the information in whatever format you like.